# set domain to subdirectory and subdomain to root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an existed website using CodeIgniter.
My CodeIgniter use only proccessing subdomain url.
The main domain, using Wordpress (the wordpress files are in subdirectory).
I use Wordpress as the landing page.

I use this htaccess below to make maindomain.com, accessing the wordpress directory.
(All wordpress url is working fine, including the wp-admin.)

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.maindomain.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wordpress/
    RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1 [L]
```

When user access `[username].maindomain.com` user get the subdomain content correctly.
But when user access any menu, eg. `[username].maindomain.com/school` a 404 Not Found error comes.

I expected that **any url without subdomain**, access **wordpress directory**.
And **url with subdomain**, access **root directory**.

Thank you very much for the advices...

**SOLVED**

```
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.maindomain\.com$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^maindomain.com$ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.maindomain.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1 [L]
```

hope helps someone who get similiar problem.

Comment: ```RewriteRule ^(.*) /wordpress/$1 [L]```

Comment: you can create different virtual hosts if you are using Linux

Comment: Like mentioned before: Create different virtual hosts (not only for Linux). This is a more clean solution. Both virtual hosts can share the same file.